# How to delete duplicate edges by inV outV and specific properties?

Tags: gremlin

I have duplicate edges in graph, which have same inV, outV and some, but not all, properties. I would like to remove all but one of those duplicates.

Given following graph:

```
g.addV().property(id, '1').
addV().property(id, '2').
addV().property(id, '3').
addV().property(id, '4').
addE('link').property('prop1', 000).property('prop2', 111).from(V('1')).to(V('2')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 000).property('prop2', 112).from(V('1')).to(V('2')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 000).property('prop2', 113).from(V('1')).to(V('2')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 222).property('prop2', 333).from(V('2')).to(V('3')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 222).property('prop2', 334).from(V('2')).to(V('3')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 222).property('prop2', 335).from(V('2')).to(V('3')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 222).property('prop2', 336).from(V('2')).to(V('3')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 333).property('prop2', 444).from(V('2')).to(V('3')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 333).property('prop2', 444).from(V('3')).to(V('4')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 333).property('prop2', 445).from(V('3')).to(V('4')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 333).property('prop2', 446).from(V('3')).to(V('4')).iterate()
```

I would like to delete all duplicates by `inV`, `outV` and `prop1` so only following edges would be left:

```
addE('link').property('prop1', 000).property('prop2', 111).from(V('1')).to(V('2')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 222).property('prop2', 336).from(V('2')).to(V('3')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 333).property('prop2', 444).from(V('2')).to(V('3')).
addE('link').property('prop1', 333).property('prop2', 446).from(V('3')).to(V('4'))
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want to deduplicate edges by checking `inV`, `outV` and `prop1`, if there are more than one edge with all these 3 parameters matching I want to keep one and remove the rest, regardless if `prop2` is unique or not.

Comment: i can't detect the pattern from your expected results, what is the exact decision criteria around properties for removal?

Comment: So I want to go over each node,  take all their edges, check if there are more than one edges where inV, outV and prop1 are same, if they are same then keep one and remove rest, regardless if prop2 is unique or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g.E().as('e').outV().id().as('ov').
  select('e').inV().id().as('iv').
  select('e').properties('prop1').value().as('p1').
  select('e', 'ov', 'iv', 'p1').
  group().
    by(select('ov', 'iv', 'p1')).
    by(select('e')).
  select(values).as('unique_e').
  V().outE().where(without('unique_e')).drop()
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I had almost the same for selecting the duplicate values, but I couldn't figure out how to do the dropping without deleting all edges. Awesome!

Comment: this just deleted all Edges from my Graph.. not sure why, yet

Comment: @Meike can you paste your graph here

Answer (score 3):

I think that the nature of your removal criteria (specifically, that you just want to immediately `drop()` duplicates you come across) allows for us to use a modification of the [Duplicate Edge Detection Pattern](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#duplicate-edge) described in Gremlin Recipes.

```
gremlin> g.V().as('ov').
......1>   outE().as('e').
......2>   inV().as('iv').
......3>   sideEffect(inE().
......4>              where(neq('e')).
......5>              where(eq('e')).by(label).
......6>              where(outV().as('ov')).
......7>              where(eq('e')).by('prop1').drop()).iterate()
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[0][1-link->2]
==>e[3][2-link->3]
==>e[7][2-link->3]
==>e[8][3-link->4]
```

The general pattern deviates as you don't care about "detecting" the duplicates (thus the expense of grouping and count filtering is not needed), you simply care about immediately dropping any duplicates that match your criteria.

The only thing that might be tricky here is if the specific graph you're using is especially eager in evaluating traversing steps. In other words, if you `drop()` an edge is it immediately removed from the future iteration of in lines 1 and 3? If not, that might spell some trouble. However, most graphs tend to work as demonstrated below (I tested on TinkerGraph) so perhaps this approach will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, though I am using Amazon Neptune in production which doesn't support sideEffect function unfortunately. I did test the above answer in smaller graph in Neptune and it did work, I do not know how it will work in a bigger graph.

Comment: you can use `local()` or `map()` instead - should work similarly. I think that you'd see better performance with this approach compared with the other answer as you don't have to build a `Map` and then reiterate `V()`. but i think both will be expensive/impossible traversals if you are globally detecting duplicates. Ideally, you would want use OLAP based Gremlin with Spark to help solve this problem, but I'm not sure Neptune supports that. On the other hand, if you execute this traversal locally for a known set of vertices with duplication problems then i suspect it will be more manageable.

Comment: Ah interesting, alright, I'll try it with `local()`. Yeah I am also afraid that it will be impossible to run on actual dataset, atleast the whole thing, and yeah Neptune does not support OLAP. I hope I might be able to constraint the traversal enough that I can do it in multiple steps.

Comment: indeed much more elegant than mine